# How to get clientHeight of a div in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to console log the div which has ref attribute :

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

function App() {
    const myRef = useRef();
    console.log(myRef.clientHeight);
    return (
        <div>
            <div ref={myRef}>div</div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

But I receive null in console :

```
App.js:5 undefined
App.js:5 undefined
```

How can I get a div's clientHieght in react ?

Comment: `myRef` will not be valid until first render, use `useEffect`,   `useEffect` is called after mount and clientHeight will then be valid.   `useEffect(() => console.log(myRef.current.clientHeight), [])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access any elements using `ref`, you will get it from the `current` property.

Like `myRef.current.clientHeight`

Learn more about accessing ref https://www.freakyjolly.com/owl-carousel-2-customize-navigation-next-prev-arrows/#.X9u8hVMzb64